# iterate checkbox javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a function for select/check all checkbox that id=hap

```
$(function () {
       $('#select-all').click(function (event) {

           var selected = this.checked;
           
           $('#hap').each(function () {    this.checked = selected; });

       });
    });
```

This is my checkbox to select all.

```
<input type='checkbox' id='select-all'><label for='select-all'>Delete all</label>
```

And I use it for select data that I've fetched by php

```
$data=mysql_query("SELECT*FROM comment where news_id='$id'");
    $x=0;
    while($a=mysql_fetch_array($data)){
                                        
    $x++;
    echo"

<td class='center'>
    <input id='hap' type='checkbox' name='c_$x' value='$a[comment_id]'>
</td>";

}
```

But it just select/check one data in the first loop, another data isn't selected.

Anyone know what's wrong with it?

Comment: Please use **PDO** or **MySQLi** instead of the old **mysql_*** functions, because it's depreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ID's are unique. If you have more than one ID on a page it will only use the first. If you need more than one of something on a page you need to use Class instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. Change `id` to `class`

```
 echo"

<td class='center'>
    <input class='hap' type='checkbox' name='c_$x' value='$a[comment_id]'>
</td>";
```

In js

```
$(function () {
       $('#select-all').click(function (event) {

           if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(".hap").attr('checked', 'checked');
    } else {
        $(".hap").removeAttr('checked');
    }


});
```

Comment: may you consider to use `.prop()` instead `.attr()` (if jq version is 1.6+) http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function actualizarSeleccion(){
   $('.hap').each(function () {    
       this.checked = document.getElementById("select-all").checked;; 
   });
}    

<input type='checkbox' id='select-all' onchange="actualizarSeleccion()"><label for='select-all'>Delete all</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you like this way:

```
$(function () {
     $('#select-all').click(function() {
          $(".hap").prop("checked", this.checked);
     });
});
```

- without set a useless variables
- without use each method (instead use prop in jquery collection of object)